# TimePicker If CheckBox IsChecked

Tags: android, timepicker, findviewbyid, android-checkbox

I'm trying to put in the Time Picker Dialog a CheckBox Above The Time Picker That just if it's checked the Time Picker Will Work.
I've trie'd to make CheckBox in the TimePickerFragment(onCreateDialog) and it putted the checkbox in the Main Activity, and not in the Time Dialog.
the TimePickerFragment:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    private MyAlarmReceiver alarm;
    //final CheckBox chk=null;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chk);
        if (chk.isChecked()) {
            chk.setChecked(false);
        }
        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        Context con = getActivity();
        MainActivity.hour = hourOfDay;
        MainActivity.min = minute;
        //Toast.makeText(con, "TimeGet: "+MainActivity.hour+","+MainActivity.min, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alarm = new MyAlarmReceiver();
        if(alarm != null){alarm.setOnetimeTimer(con);}
        else
            Toast.makeText(con, "Alarm is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@drawable/back" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/chk" 
        android:checked="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any idea why?Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `findViewById()` method for Fragments, hence the error.

Since it seems you want to get a reference to the Activity's Checkbox, getting the Activity instance then calling `findViewById()` should give the desired result:

```
final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.chk);
if (chk.isChecked()) {
     chk.setChecked(false);
}
```

And as ChriZzZ mentioned, unreachable code is another compiler error that you should encounter.

Comment: Thanks.But It's put's the checkbox in my main activity and not in my TimePickerDialog(I've Edited)

Comment: @elichai2 If you want the Checkbox to appear in your Dialog, why is it part of the Activity's layout? I say to review the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) and mess with the View methods provided or make a plain Dialog, then add a TimePicker and a Checkbox to it.

Comment: because i didn't find how can i create CheckBox without making it in the xml, and i thought that maybe it will work for me(probably i was wrong)
So how can i do that(i saw nothing on the View methods at the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I am quite sure you get a warning/error that says: Unreachable Code.

You return and therefore leave the method before you even reach findViewById.

```
// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));

final CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chk);
```

Comment: Thanks to you too.But It's put's the checkbox in my main activity and not in my TimePickerDialog(I've Edited)